# Onclick enable the clicked image and disable the others images

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, onclick, jquery-events

I want to create an event with Javascript `onclick` that will enable the clicked image and will disable others.

For example, if I have 6 pictures, how can I do the following: I want to click any picture for example picture number 3, then picture number 3 will be enabled and the pictures 1,2,4,5,6 will be disabled.

A few seconds after, I want to click on picture number 1, then it will become active and 2,3,4,5,6 will be disabled.

How can I do this?

Comment: images don't really have a enabled/disabled state so you need to clarify what you mean. Also, You need to provide the code you have already tried.

Comment: Well, i have some category for different locations like: pubs, fun, shopping and others. I work with Google Maps API. I want something like this.. when i click on the icon "fun" need to change the icon..on active. For the beginning all the icons are gray, but when i click one of the icons the clicked icon need to change in the icon with color red and to show me all the marker for the icon selected. If i will click on the icon 'fun' all other icons will be gray (disabled) and the "fun" icon will be changed in red icon and the API need to show me the markers from category fun.

Comment: Then, if i want to click on the icon gray with the category shopping, clicking this icon all others icons will be changed with the gray icon and the clicked icon will be red..I' ve tried this code, but it's a toggle, i don't want this
                for (var i = 0; i < markerGroups[type].length; i++) {
                    var marker = markerGroups[type][i];
                    if (!marker.getVisible()) {
                        marker.setVisible(true);
                    } else {
                         marker.setVisible(false);
                    }
                }
            }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using [jQuery Siblings](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/)

Here an example:

```
$(function(){
  $("img").click(function(){
    $(this).addClass("on").siblings("img").removeClass("on");
  });
});
```

Edit, working example:

```js
$(function(){
  var replaceImg = function($img){ 
    var src0= $img.attr("src");
    var src1= $img.data("on-src");
    $img.attr("src",src1).data("on-src",src0);    
  };
  $("img").click(function(){   
    $(this).addClass("on");
    replaceImg($(this));
    
     $(this).siblings("img").each(
      
     function(){
       var $this = $(this);
        if($this.hasClass("on")){
          $(this).removeClass("on");
          replaceImg($(this));
          }
     }
     );
  });
});
```

```css
img{border:solid 3px black;}
img.on{border:solid 3px red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>



<div>
 <img src="https://67.media.tumblr.com/avatar_0c16e55c511b_128.png" data-on-src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/jonathan-rey/simpsons/128/Homer-Simpson-04-Happy-icon.png">
 <img src="https://67.media.tumblr.com/avatar_0c16e55c511b_128.png" data-on-src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/jonathan-rey/simpsons/128/Homer-Simpson-04-Happy-icon.png">
   <img src="https://67.media.tumblr.com/avatar_0c16e55c511b_128.png" data-on-src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/jonathan-rey/simpsons/128/Homer-Simpson-04-Happy-icon.png">
   <img src="https://67.media.tumblr.com/avatar_0c16e55c511b_128.png" data-on-src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/jonathan-rey/simpsons/128/Homer-Simpson-04-Happy-icon.png">
   <img src="https://67.media.tumblr.com/avatar_0c16e55c511b_128.png" data-on-src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/jonathan-rey/simpsons/128/Homer-Simpson-04-Happy-icon.png">
</div>
```

Edit 2 - For Change the image

Comment: Thanks man, i'm closer:p. I want to change the image not the border, is this possible? And it's another image for every picture..if i will click the first image she will be chenged with a unique image..clicking the second image will do the same, will have a unique image.

Comment: You can do it, i'm just changing the border to show you an example. The basic logic will be the same.